# How to publish Blazor app to github pages in 2023?

Tags: .net, github, blazor, github-actions

I have tried all day to try and upload my Blazor project to Github pages but I always end in a 404 error.
[image]
I have tried the yaml below, as well as copying and pasting wwwroot to the repository root.

`name: Deploy to GitHub Pages

## Run workflow on every push to the master branch: workflow trigger

on:
push:
branches:
- master
pull_request:
branches:
- master

jobs:
deploy-to-github-pages:

## use ubuntu-latest image to run steps on

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
# uses GitHub's checkout action to checkout code form the main branch
- uses: actions/checkout@v2

# sets up .NET Core SDK 7.0.x
- name: Setup .NET Core SDK
  uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
  with:
    dotnet-version: 7.0.x

 # Install dotnet wasm buildtools workload
- name: Install .NET WASM Build Tools
  run: dotnet workload install wasm-tools

# Publishes Blazor project to the release-folder
- name: Publish .NET Core Project
  run: dotnet publish Portfolio/Portfolio.csproj -c:Release -p:GHPages=true -o dist/Web --nologo

# changes the base-tag in index.html from '/' to 'WebPortfolio' to match GitHub Pages repository subdirectory
- name: Change base-tag in index.html from / to WebPortfolio
  run: sed -i 's/<base href="\/" \/>/<base href="\/WebPortfolio\/" \/>/g' release/wwwroot/index.html

#Publish static files to Github pages
- name: Commit wwwroot to GitHub Pages
  uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@3.7.1
  with:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    BRANCH: gh-pages
    FOLDER: dist/Web/wwwroot`
```

Comment: The `sed` command line: change `release` to `dist/Web`?

Answer (score 1):

As @Sir Rufo mentioned in the comments. You need to change your `sed` step to

```
      - name: Change base-tag in index.html from / to WebPortfolio
        run: sed -i 's/<base href="\/" \/>/<base href="\/WebPortfolio\/" \/>/g' dist/Web/wwwroot/index.html
```

Those fix your current steps however, to fully deploy to github pages, You need to add more steps, which add the `.nojekyll`, `404.html`

**Code from**: [Swimburger.net article](https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-deploy-aspnet-blazor-webassembly-to-github-pages#summary)

> ```
> # Copy index.html to 404.html to serve the same file when a file is not found
> - name: Copy index.html to 404.html
>   run: cp dist/Web/wwwroot/index.html dist/Web/wwwroot/404.html
>
> # Add .nojekyll file to tell GitHub Pages to not treat this as a Jekyll project. (Allow files and folders starting with an underscore)
> - name: Add .nojekyll file
>   run: touch dist/Web/wwwroot/.nojekyll
> ```

### Using package

Or, save yourself some headache and use this package where all of those steps are handled for you.

[PublishSPAforGitHubPages](https://github.com/jsakamoto/PublishSPAforGitHubPages.Build)

Comment: That helped in the sense that it now shows "loading" instead of a 404, but I'm getting a ton of console errors still like: cv145.github.io/:49 
        GET https://cv145.github.io/WebPortfolio/brotliloader.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: are you using the package?

Comment: This `-p:GHPages=true` is a command for that package. If you're not using it you need to remove that.

Comment: I am getting this error on publishing the yaml file: /home/runner/work/WebPortfolio/WebPortfolio/Portfolio/wwwroot/Pages/Index.razor.js : error BLAZOR106: The JS module file '/home/runner/work/WebPortfolio/WebPortfolio/Portfolio/wwwroot/Pages/Index.razor.js' was defined but no associated razor component or view was found for it. [/home/runner/work/WebPortfolio/WebPortfolio/Portfolio/Portfolio.csproj]